# Kivy - Label text is not changing

Tags: python, kivy

My first question here :), and probably a simple one for you guys...
I have problem with label text change when I press button.

Code is below. 
I have tried many variations of on_press definition:

```
self.on_press=lambda:YellowLabel.change_text(YellowLabel)
self.on_press=lambda:YellowLabel.change_text
```

does not work

```
self.on_press=YellowLabel.change_text(YellowLabel)
```

returns:

> KeyError: 'text'

I guess this is probably due to conflict because function is called before Label is initialized.  When I tried

`self.on_press=YellowLabel.change_text`

it returns:

> TypeError: change_text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I have also tried many other variations, but I just can not get it.
And , print function inside change_text is working in example below, but Label text is not changing.
i have also tried to put change_text outside YellowLabel class, but still no luck...

What am i doing wrong?
Now, i am thinking that maybe change_text function is not good, but I can not understand why...

p.s. i did went thru many kivy related questions on this site, and tried them, but I just can not get it working.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class RedButton(Button):
    def __init__(self,txt="RED LABEL",**kwargs):
        super(RedButton,self).__init__(txt="RED LABEL",**kwargs)
        self.text=(txt)
        self.color=[1,0,0,1]
        self.on_press=lambda:YellowLabel.change_text(YellowLabel)


class YellowLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(YellowLabel,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text=("yellow")
        self.color=[1,1,0,1]
        self.id="yelb"

    def change_text(self):
        print("printed")
        self.text=("new yellow text")   

class Window(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Window,self).__init__(orientation="vertical",**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(RedButton(txt="new red button"))
        self.add_widget(YellowLabel())

class UpdateApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Window()

if __name__=="__main__":
    UpdateApp().run()
```

Comment: try `self.on_press=lambda:YellowLabel.change_text()`

Comment: nope... i get this error:
TypeError: change_text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: I'd say the problem might be that here `self.on_press=lambda:YellowLabel.change_text(YellowLabel)` you're missing reference to YellowLable that you have created in Window `__init__`  . You should try to get YellowLable widget from Window object and call `change_text()` on that

Comment: ha, you are right... it works.. will you create answer so that I can approwe i? or how does it goes? here is mine Window code (i can not format it in comments??)
    rb=RedButton(txt="new red button")

    self.add_widget(rb)

    yl=YellowLabel()
    self.add_widget(yl)
    rb.on_press=lambda:YellowLabel.change_text(yl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the problem might be that here `self.on_press=lambda:YellowLabel.change_text(YellowLabel)` you're missing reference to YellowLable that you have created in Window `__init__` . You should try to get YellowLable widget from Window object and call `change_text()` on that

Your code from comment ( after all you figured it out yourself :-) ):

```
class Window(BoxLayout):
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            super(Window,self).__init__(orientation="vertical",**kwargs)
            rb=RedButton(txt="new red button")
            self.add_widget(rb)
            yl=YellowLabel()
            self.add_widget(yl)
            rb.on_press=lambda:YellowLabel.change_text(yl)
```